# RecyclerView scrolls over the content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a RecyclerView below an AppBar/CollapsingToolbar inside a CoordinatorLayout and even when the list only has 2 items, I can scroll over it and collapse the toolbar. After that there is a huge space under my list items.

Why does it happen? What shall I do?

Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleMargin="16dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:titleMarginStart="16dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_padding"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Could you provide the layout you're using?

Comment: My whole activity layout.

Comment: Try removing the bottom padding on RecyclerView